# How To Declare Static Const Array

Tags: c++, arrays, static

I coded like this in class with public modifier:

```
    static const string brands[] = {"Coca-Cola","Pepsi","Ruffles"};
```

And it gives me this error code:

> E1591

How can I solve that ?

Comment: Please include the *full* error text. Not everyone knows random compiler error codes by number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you can't have in-class initializer for your `static const std::string []`.

You should initialize it outside the class declaration.
For instance:

```
#include <string>
class Foo
{
public:
  static const std::string brands[];

};

// in your Foo.cpp file
const std::string Foo::brands[] = {"Coca-Cola","Pepsi","Ruffles"};
```

Comment: Or `static inline const string brands[] = {"Coca-Cola","Pepsi","Ruffles"};` in class declaration works too. (since C++17)

Comment: @Sprite: ah yes, this is fine for C++17 with no warning. With C++14 on my Ubuntu 18, it produces a warning (`warning: inline variables are only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z`), though I can still compile it.

Answer (score -1):

The C++ answer is to skip using C arrays, which have limitations in C++ not present in C, and instead use `std::vector`:

```cpp
static const std::vector<std::string> brands = {"Coca-Cola","Pepsi","Ruffles"};
```

> Note the `std::` prefix which should be present as `using namespace std` can be highly problematic for a variety of reasons, most of all name conflict. The prefix exists for a reason.

Comment: @Raildex Matter of opinion. Unless `std::vector` is causing problems it's usually fine. The number of cases where I've seen `std::array` be necessary are shockingly few. It can be slightly more efficient if that's ever an issue.